# browser compatibility issue when creating scrolling bar

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some divs lets say 100 and These boxes are horizontal, I also have 2 arrows and when mouse is positioned over them they move the box to right or left,

[image]

the ptoblem is when I put mouse over the left arrow it should move left if the first box is not in its actual(at loading time) postion but if it is in its positin it should be locked and not move any more It works in chrome but in other borwsers looks like this:

[image]

my code also looks like this:
           function shiftToLeft() {
                              firstEntity = $(".entities").first();
                              entityWidth = firstEntity.outerWidth();
                              entitiesAreaWidth = $("#slideshow_entity").width();

```
            if (firstEntity.offset().left != entitiesAreaWidth - entityWidth)
                firstEntity.animate({
                    'marginRight' : "+=4px"
                }, 0);
            else
                $("#slideshow_entity_arrow_left").css('background-image',
                        "url(" + leftArrowNormal + ")");
        }
```

could you please help me? what is wrong that it is only working on chrome (only on windows operating system )?(sorry I could not align part of code above properly )

Comment: Could you please post a JSFiddle?

Comment: This is the link but since it is a very big project and many resources combined together to return the result back I could not put all in fiddle head but at least you can see html and javasdript easier thanks:)   http://jsfiddle.net/hminaee/eeSqH/

Comment: also it is noteworthy that the Html that I added is a component that would be added to a jsp file

Comment: Well, given the scope of your project that didn't help at all! I'm going to give it a shot here.

Comment: Thanks I do not know how to put the project in fiddle I think it is not possible

Comment: But if anyone have had the same issue he may be able to figure this browser compatibility issue!!

Comment: I can tell you that I have run into styling issues with Chrome. Namely, margins. You should try to do some debugging.


    console.log(firstEntity.outerWidth());
    console.log($("#slideshow_entity").width());
    console.log(firstEntity.css('marginLeft'));
    console.log(firstEntity.css('marginRight'));
    console.log($("#slideshow_entity").offset().left); ..... Could you tell me what you get and edit it in your question? In Chrome and at least one browser where it does not work.

Comment: Thanks for your constructive reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the following line instead:

if (Math.ceil(firstEntity.offset().left) != entitiesAreaWidth - entityWidth)